# How is Professor X still paralyzed and bald after X-Men Days of Future Past?

Tags: marvel, movie, x-men

Wolverine was sent back in time and he changed the timeline. But if he changed the events of X-Men: First Class, Apocalypse, etc. then how did he get paralyzed and bald?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In the X-Men movie franchise, were the third and fourth movie written out of the timeline?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/in-the-x-men-movie-franchise-were-the-third-and-fourth-movie-written-out-of-the), specifically [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/84834/98028)

Comment: We [don't delete duplicates](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7944/31394) because they're useful signposts (especially in this case where the titles are nothing alike).